# Stop reading from file when it can't read anymore using BinData

Tags: ruby, bindata

Currently I'm using the [BinData gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bindata) to parse a binary file format. It works just fine, except I'm not sure where to stop. The file is divided into properties that I read using BinData Records. There can be anywhere between 16 and 18 properties (depending on the file it takes). So, if I do this:

```
16.times{
    # parse data from property.
}
```

That works fine when there are 16 properties, however, if I bump it up to 17 I get the following error.

```
'readbytes': End of file reached (EOFError)
```

My question is, how can I just avoid the 16 times all together and have it read until it reads all the properties it can, then stops when it reaches this end of file error.

Comment: Can you treat the file as an array and use `read_until: :eof`?

Comment: I supposed I asked the question a little prematurely. After looking into the file more it appears as if it ends with a string terminator. I can just look for that and stop reading. Thanks for the help once again though!

Comment: When asking about a problem with your code we expect the minimal example of your code demonstrating the problem. Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

From [examples/tcp_ip.rb](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata/blob/0e0e636364647e14f03853993490d10a5edf30f5/examples/tcp_ip.rb#L158):

```
  class PcapFile < BinData::Record
    endian :little

    struct :head do
      uint32 :magic
      uint16 :major
      uint16 :minor
      int32  :this_zone
      uint32 :sig_figs
      uint32 :snaplen
      uint32 :linktype
    end

    array :records, :read_until => :eof do
      uint32 :ts_sec
      uint32 :ts_usec
      uint32 :incl_len
      uint32 :orig_len
      string :data, :length => :incl_len
    end
  end
```

The approach taken in that example is to tell BinData that there is an array of records, and then let them read them all.